# Not able to add HTML to <ui:define>

Tags: java, jsf-2, facelets

I have recently started working with JSF2.0 and Facelets, but have run into what I hope is an easy answer for most of you out there.  When I am trying to add any HTML tag within a `<ui:define>` tag I receive the following error:

> javax.faces.view.facelets.TagException: /content/home/test.xhtml @11,10  Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets, but no tag was defined for name: div

If I remove all of the HTML tags from the section the page displays correctly. Here is my simple page that I have been trying to get working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:jrc="http://com.comanche.web.components"> 
<ui:composition template="/templates/masterLayout.xhtml" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">      

    <ui:define name="windowTitle">Home</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">
            <div>I want to add HTML and am having lots of trouble.</div>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

I know I should be able to add HTML within the define tag.  What do I need to do to get HTML in without any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<ui:composition>` declaration is using the wrong global XML namespace. You definied `http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets` as global XML namespace while it should have been assigned to `ui:` XML namespace. The `<div>` tag doesn't exist in the Facelets taglib (which is what the exception is trying to tell you). You should have assigned `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` as global XML namespace. Further, the `<!DOCTYPE>` and `<html>` will be ignored anyway. The **sole** content of the file should be the following:

```html
<ui:composition template="/templates/masterLayout.xhtml" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">      

    <ui:define name="windowTitle">Home</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">
        <div>I want to add HTML and am having lots of trouble.</div>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Nothing before or after `<ui:composition>` in the very same file is necessary.

#### See also:

- [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets)